# Fence node in apache traffic server

Tags: http, reverse-proxy, high-availability

I'm currently looking into Apache Traffic Server as a tool for providing better availability of web services.

But looking at the manual I can't see any reference to how I can pro-actively fence a node in the cluster. While the other nodes will take over the virtual IP if I shut down an instance, according to the manual the failover takes approx 30 seconds to detect and respond.

Is there a way to remove a node from the cluster gracefully?